# Magento Hello World Admin Module Returning 404

Tags: magento, module, admin

I'm having a go at building an admin module using the moduleCreator tool found [here](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)

Even out of the box it is throwing a 404 when I navigate to the page.  I have disabled cash and logged out/in. None of the googled solutions fix the issue.  I am running 1.7.2

The key files look like this:

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Jinkou_MobileAdmin>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Jinkou_MobileAdmin>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <mobileadmin>
        <class>Jinkou_MobileAdmin_Helper</class>
      </mobileadmin>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <mobileadmin>
        <class>Jinkou_MobileAdmin_Block</class>
      </mobileadmin>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <mobileadmin>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Jinkou_MobileAdmin</module>
          <frontName>mobileadmin</frontName>
        </args>
      </mobileadmin>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <mobileadmin module="mobileadmin">
        <title>MobileAdmin</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <mobileadminbackend module="mobileadmin">
            <title>Order Processing</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>mobileadmin/adminhtml_mobileadminbackend</action>
          </mobileadminbackend>
        </children>
      </mobileadmin>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <mobileadmin translate="title" module="mobileadmin">
              <title>MobileAdmin</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <mobileadminbackend translate="title">
            <title>Order Processing</title>
          </mobileadminbackend>
              </children>
            </mobileadmin>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <mobileadmin>
          <file>mobileadmin.xml</file>
        </mobileadmin>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**MobileBackendController.php**

```
<?php
class Jinkou_MobileAdmin_Adminhtml_MobileAdminbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->_title($this->__("Order Processing"));
       $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

The MobileAdminbackendController.php does not seem to be loading as I can remove the class and not throw an exception.

Comment: I think you might have missed to add mobileadmin.xml inside app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout

Comment: It is there and it is empty at the moment

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <mobileadmin_adminhtml_mobileadminbackend_index>
 <reference name="content">
   <block type="mobileadmin/adminhtml_mobileadminbackend" name="mobileadminbackend" template="mobileadmin/mobileadminbackend.phtml"/>
 </reference>
  </mobileadmin_adminhtml_mobileadminbackend_index>
</layout>

Comment: it must have the above code

Comment: I have put it in and it is still 404, the template file is also in place

Comment: One other thing springs to mind, we have the store code appended to the url so /admin is now /admin/admin would this have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to the following settings page and check if you can fing "Jinkou_MobileAdmin" in the list?

```
System -> Configuration -> Advanced
```

If you can't find it there, you might have forgotten to add the module XML file in your code, to add this, go to:

```
app -> etc -> modules
```

Just copy other XML and edit the data in it to your module.
Make sure you name your file "Jinkou_MobileAdmin.xml".

Comment: Module is there and active

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the following files are there inside the proper folders as given below :

```
 app\code\local\Jinkou\MobileAdmin\Block\Adminhtml\MobileAdminbackend.php
 app\code\local\Jinkou\MobileAdmin\controllers\Adminhtml\MobileAdminbackendController.php
 app\code\local\Jinkou\MobileAdmin\etc\config.xml
 app\code\local\Jinkou\MobileAdmin\Helper\Data.php

 app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\mobileadmin.xml
 app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\mobileadmin\mobileadminbackend.phtml

 app\etc\modules\Jinkou_MobileAdmin.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on `magento 1.8` and I fixed my error(404) by doing the following. Inside `Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml` put below code:

`codePool local codePool`

since I do not have a local folder I put mine into the community folder. Change the code to this and it will work.

'codePool  community  codePool'